# How to call a method defined on the iPhone from the Apple Watch

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

Is there any way to call a defined method in a class on the iPhone from the Watchkit extension?

From my understanding currently one of the ways to communicate locally between Watch kit and the iPhone is by using `NSUserDefaults`, but are there other ways?

A simple example would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For WatchOS2 `openParentApplication` is deprecated. The replacement for it is `WCSession` in [Watch Connectivity Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WatchConnectivity_framework/)

First, initialize `WCSession` in both watch(`ExtensionDelegate`)& iOS(`AppDelegate`) with following code

```
if WCSession.isSupported() {
  let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
  session.delegate = self
  session.activateSession()
}
```

Send a notification from watch to Phone using

```
session.sendMessage(msg, replyHandler: { (responses) -> Void in
  print(responses)
 }) { (err) -> Void in
 print(err)
}
```

Handle the message in `AppDelegate` using

```
func session(_ session: WCSession,
             didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject],
             replyHandler replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void)     
{
   //do something according to the message dictionary
   responseMessage = ["key" : "value"] //values for the replyHandler
   replyHandler(responseMessage)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can add the class to both targets (main iOS app and WatchKit extention) and use methods in WatchKit Extention directly.

[image: Uncluding to targets]

Conveniently add classes (preferable utilities or categories) with few dependencies.
If file is already added to project, you can delete it (remove reference) and add it once again with including to multiple targets.

For example, my category NSString+color in project works correctly in iOS app and Watch App.

Upd: You can also do it in right panel (Utilities). See the link bellow: [cs621620.vk.me/v621620973/13f86/9XYDH1HL5BI.jpg](http://cs621620.vk.me/v621620973/13f86/9XYDH1HL5BI.jpg)

Comment: How did you do this? I am unable to see the option where I can add to multiple targets, although I have already created a target for the WatchKit App.

Comment: Can this be done to a file once you've already added it to the project? I know you can remove the reference and add the file again and this dialogue box will be shown, however I'm looking for a swifter way to do it.

Comment: You can also do it in right panel (Utilities) http://cs621620.vk.me/v621620973/13f86/9XYDH1HL5BI.jpg

Comment: Hey i did the same in my project but my watch app compiling this class and some other class as well which i have not added to watch Extension Target and getting error because of that. what could be the issue?

Comment: This works with some classes.  However, I am having an issue with any class that has links to SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration framework.  Any Ideas?

Comment: John, in this case you can use WCSession in Watch Connectivity Framework. Your iOS app will be started in background (if not started yet), so you can call all required methods in the parent app and send the result into your WatchKit app.

Answer (score 4):

There are two main ways to 'communicate' between your WatchKit Extension and iOS application depending on the what you are trying to accomplish.

**1. openParentApplication:reply:** 

This will open your iOS application in the background and allow you to perform logic from your iOS code and send a response back to your Extension. For example -

```
    [InterfaceController openParentApplication:@{ @"command": @"foo" }
                                         reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {
                                         self.item = replyInfo[@"bar"];
    }];
```

Checkout the Framework Reference -https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/WKInterfaceController/openParentApplication:reply:

MMWormhole is a library that you can use to manage these communications

**2. Shared Container**

If you just need access to the same data that your iOS application has access to you can implement shared containers across both targets.

This could range from just using accessing a shared NSUserDefaults, as you've mentioned or all the way up to using Core Data and accessing a shared persistence stack across both iOS and WatchKit.

Programming Reference - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2408/_index.html

**3. Singleton**

Perhaps you just need to access shared logic from your WatchKit Extension but don't need the complexity of the above two options. As long as you're not persisting any data across both targets you could create a Singleton class that you can call from your Extension to perform the methods you need.

Comment: Why can't I just call an instance method?

Answer (score 3):

According to Apple's [WatchKit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/index.html) you can communicate with the iOS app on the iPhone by using `openParentApplication` and pass a dictionary. The parent application handles this call via `handleWatchKitExtensionsRequest` in its `AppDelegate`. From there you can call other methods depending on the passed parameters.

`handleWatchKitExtensionRequest` then calls the `reply` method to pass back parameters to the WatchKit Extension:

**Watchkit Extension:**

```
// Call the parent application from Apple Watch

// values to pass
let parentValues = [
    "value1" : "Test 1",
    "value2" : "Test 2"
]

WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(parentValues, reply: { (replyValues, error) -> Void in
    println(replyValues["retVal1"])
    println(replyValues["retVal2"])
})
```

**iOS App:**

```
// in AppDelegate.swift
func application(application: UIApplication!, handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!) {
    // retrieved parameters from Apple Watch
    println(userInfo["value1"])
    println(userInfo["value2"])

    // pass back values to Apple Watch
    var retValues = Dictionary<String,String>()

    retValues["retVal1"] = "return Test 1"
    retValues["retVal2"] = "return Test 2"

    reply(retValues)
}
```

Note that this seems to be broken in Xcode 6.2 Beta 3.

Comment: "Note that this seems currently to be broken in Xcode 6.2 Beta 3."—Not in my experience, though I am using Objective C code which could be the difference.

Comment: Why can't I just call an instance method?

Comment: To me it also seems to be broken. I'm trying to make a watch kit extension communicate with an Objective C app.